# can't press image-buttons in python tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, button

I created non-existing 1px image, so i can set it to the button and set width and height by pixels. But for  some reason, i can't press the button after that. And for some reason the function runs even without clicking it. What am i doing wrong?

```
class ShowHide:
def show_hide(self, buttons):
    buttons.pack_forget()
    self.show()

class Page(Frame):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
def show(self):
    self.lift()
def back(self):
    pass

class GPUs(Page):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Page.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        pixel = PhotoImage(width=1, height=1)
        amd_frame = AMD(self)
        nvidia_frame = NVIDIA(self)
        intel_frame = INTEL(self)
        container = Frame(self)
        amd_frame.place(in_=container, x=0, y=41, relwidth=1, relheight=10)

        amd_button = Button(container, text='AMD', width=(window.winfo_width() // 3),
                            command=lambda: ShowHide.show_hide(amd_frame, container),
                            image=pixel, font=('consolas', 24), compound='c', height=40)

        amd_button.grid(row=0, column=0)
        container.place(x=0, y=0)
```

Comment: This isn't a runnable example -- too many things missing -- but I do want to point out a problem.  `ShowHide.show_hide` is calling that as a class method.  It will not have a `self` parameter, because you didn't create an object.  I'm not sure what you expected `self.show()` to do in that function.

Answer (score 2):

The root of the problem is that your `pixel` image is a local variable, so when it goes out of scope it gets destroyed. This seems to inhibit the functioning of the button.

The simplest solution is to replace `pixel` with `self.pixel`.